# Unlocking cells based on specific month in a set of dates in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a problem with properly setting a VBA code in order to have excel unlocking for editing only cells of a specific column in a row based on a date in another column.

I've got a range of dates (advancing by a month) in column "A", and place for inserting data i.a. in column "I". On one hand, for the purpose of different column, I need all 12 months a year in column "A", while I wanted to allow user of the sheet to do entries in column "I" only in cells of a row where there is March in column "A". Each year up to the end of the list in column "A".

So far, I tried many different examples of code for similar cases, but none of them worked. It seems that most of my problem is with the proper definition of `If` in connection with `Month` or `LMonth` formula.

Below, one of codes I tried:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim i As Integer

  For i = 2 To 319

    If Cells(i, 1).Month = "3" Then
      Cells(i, 9).Locked = False
    ElseIf Cells(i, 1).LMonth <> 3 Then
      Cells(i, 9).Locked = True
    End If

  Next i

End Sub
```

After running such code, I receive

> Runtime error '438': Object doesn't support this property or method

Spent so much time on that and still no results, so I would be really grateful for any help!
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What is LMONTH?

Comment: Is the worksheet protected?

Comment: I think you need .Text or .Value, not .Month ... if you want to get the month of a date in a cell, use Month(cell.Value), not .Month ... that’s my two cents anyway.

Comment: LMonth is something I found somewhere on the Internet as VBA equivalent to regular Month formula, but after some attempts I'm more convinced that Month is the proper one for that.

Comment: Luuklag: The worksheet isn't protected yet, but when I turned the protection on, all cells were locked - as if the macro didn't do anything.
Brad Dixon: I've got data in date format in column "A" and it starts e.g. from Jan-2013 and ends with Mar-2027, hence thought that .Month is required to "extract" only March (3) from those dates. Do you have any idea how to set it with .Text or .Value?